# Is mentioning full name on email replies considered rude?

Tags: politeness, internet

For example:

If someone replies "Sure Deepak Mishra :)" or "Sure Deepak :)".

Should "Sure Deepak Mishra :)" look offensive to me or is it not good email etiquette?

Is using a person's first name or full name in emails considered rude by today's standards?

Comment: It could be possible that the sender of the email didn't know which was your first/last name, and therefore used the whole name.

Comment: Actually It was opposite. I did this for someone and I knew their first name and last name both. And they replied back saying that it's not etiquette... ;)

Comment: One should write email in the manner in which one would actually speak. If one would say, "Hi Deepak Mishra" in a face-to-face greeting, what would your response be? "No, you can call me Deepak. Or Mr. Mishra. Or 'D'". If someone is taking a survey/attendance or calling your name at a doctor's office, it might be helpful to know that Deepak Mishra is being referenced versus Deepak Patel. Hopefully, someone who is a known acquaintance of yours being directly addressed won't need such distinction as requiring full name.

Comment: You should ask on [Writers.SE] or [Workplace.SE] instead.

Comment: “*is it good* [**email etiquette**](https://blog.hubspot.com/sales/email-etiquette-tips-rules)?” the noun is singular, we use "etiquettes" in the plural (rare) when talking about more than one type of etiquette

Comment: @Mari-LouA ok done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In casual and friendly conversations, people normally call each other by first names (or don't use names at all when the reference is clear). If you choose to use their full name, "Mr. Mishra", or a title like "Doctor", it suggests that you do not consider the conversation to be friendly. If this occurs in an online setting that's normally assumed to be casual, it will often be interpreted as confrontational. It's a common technique of trolls in online forums, replying to other posters with full names to annoy them.

Parents will sometimes use a child's full name when calling for them in order to discipline them. This is somewhat related to the above situation -- using a full name and a loud voice distinguishes it from the normal case where they would use first names or pet names. A wife might also do this when confronting her spouse (maybe that's sexist, but I've never seen it the other way around), calling them by a full name instead of "dear" or "honey".

In more formal situations, there's no special connotation to using full names. It's normal in news stories and introducing lecturers at conferences. In business correspondence, usually you would use an honorific and last name, e.g. Dr./Mr. So-and-so.

Comment: I've been trying to think of situation where one would use both names, like OP did. All I can come up with is either when identifying a person, or when a person close to you and very mad (and then they can even pull in the middle name).

Comment: So that's not offensive...that's more of leg pulling which should not look offensive in any type of emails (and can't be escalated/reported)

Comment: It really depends on the context.